# 'Bool' object not iterable : How to solve this typeError

Tags: string, validation

x=any(s.isalnum())
How to solve bool not iterable typeError?

I was finding that string containing any number or alphabet.

Is there any other option to check string containing alphabet or number or alphanumeric, etc......?

Comment: It would be helpful to get a big more context, specifically, what the variable `s` contains and what you actually want to check. If the intention is to check if `s` consists of alphanumeric letters only, `s.isalnum()` alone (without `any`) would do that:
`"abcDEF123".isalnum()` evaluates to True, `"foo$%".isalnum()` evaluates to False.
To find out if any alphanumeric letters are in the string, use `any` to check any character in s: `any(x.isalnum() for x in s)`.

Given `s = "foo$bar"`, the expression `any(t.isalnum() for t in s)` will evaluate to True.